# readfile() not working with remote resources

Tags: php, readfile

So I came at a little problem with a project of mine.  We have a bulky server with lots of space as well as a light static storage server that can **only** be used to store things.  We need to make sure only the people who are authenticated can access the resources on the static server, so I thought about making a psuedo-proxy out of readfile(), as we can use allow_url_fopen.

So I tried the following code as a test:

```
<?php
$type = "video/webm";
$loc = "http://a.pomf.se/fzggfj.webm";
header('Content-Type: '.$type);
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($loc));
readfile($loc);
exit;
```

This always fails, the browser reads this as corrupted.  Interestingly, when you do this:

```
<?php
$type = "video/webm";
$loc = "../test.webm";
header('Content-Type: '.$type);
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($loc));
readfile($loc);
exit;
```

It does work, even though the file is the exact same.  Does anyone know why readfile will not do this correctly, and explain this to me?

EDIT:
I got the error message from it, it was stuck in the file.

> Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for http://a.pomf.se/fzggfj.webm in C:\uniform\UniServerZ\www\director.php on line 5

Is filesize() my problem here?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Wavoz Have you looked at the data you're getting and how exactly it differs from the expected original?

Comment: Error reporting is turned on, but the error got stuck in the webm as it was sent to the user.

Comment: Yes, pretty obviously `filesize` is the problem, since it can't get the file size of a remote file.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I fixed it.  deceze was correct, and filesize was the issue.  Let the record show that filesize doesn't work on remote resources I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) by adding `allow_url_fopen=1` in your `php.ini`.

Comment: He indicated he has that available. I missed it too.

Comment: Check with `ini_get()`, you can't change this option with `ini_set()`.

Answer (score -1):

why You aren't downloading video to temporary directory and redirect user to there? (of course You can clear outdated tmp dir later with cron script)
try this:

```
<?php
$loc = "http://a.pomf.se/fzggfj.webm";

$pathToVideos = dirname(__FILE__).'/tmp/';
$ext = explode('.', $loc);
$ext = end($ext);
$hash = md5($loc);

$filename = $hash.'.'.$ext;
$tmpFile = $pathToVideos.$filename;
if(!is_file($tmpFile)) {
    exec('wget -O '.escapeshellarg($tmpFile).' '.escapeshellarg($loc));
}

header('Location: /tmp/'.$filename);
exit(0);
```

Comment: I can't as many of the files being sent to the users are extremely large (one is even about 3+ gigabytes).  Thank you though.

Comment: Because it's much more complex, takes longer, uses more resources, etc. etc...?!

Comment: Yes. PHP is not that tool to transfer gigs of data through http.

Comment: No but I have to use what I have to use.  Under normal circumstances, I would have made a proxy with some C.

Comment: Maybe You try to pipe data with nodejs? with it You can proxy traffic from source to destination. Amazon gives EC2 for one year free so You can build app on it.